# Do I need a stationary dependent variable before applying multilevel modeling with repeated measures?

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I have repeated measures over time about study hours of students and their performance.
I want to understand if study hours can predict performance, using a multilevel regression model with fixed effects. Repeated measures are nested within students.

If performance is not stationary, do I need to make a differencing before applying the multilevel modeling? Or can I use the dependent variable as it is?